# MS Access - Query - unique values

Tags: ms-access

I have a query where fields are as follows:

```
UniqueID | RefNum | FirstName | Surname | Aim |.....
```

UniqueID - is a unique field (no duplicates)

RefNum - contains duplicates

What I'm trying to do is to create a new query (based on the above or amend this one) to extract only records with unique RefNum (remove duplicates from the RefNum field)

The way I did it was select 'Group By' RefNum in the Query Design View and selecting 'First' for the rest of the fields. It achieves what I need.

The problem is that if I switch to the Datasheet View (and subsequently export it to excel to be sent out) the field names are 'FirstOfUniqueID', 'FirstofFirstName', 'FirstOfSurname', etc. Is there a way of keep the original field names (not prefixing them with 'FirstOf') or is there another way of achieving it?

Answer (score 1):

The query designer automatically assigns an alias for a field expression which is based on an aggregate function.  So, if you switch from *Design View* to *SQL View* for your query, you will see something like this included in the `SELECT` field list ...

```sql
First(FirstName) AS FirstOfFirstName
```

You can change the alias to something else, and you have a lot of flexibility.  However, at least in some cases, when you attempt to re-use the base field name as the alias, Access complains about a "circular reference".  I don't know whether that would happen here, but you can try it like this ...

```sql
First(FirstName) AS [FirstName]
```

Whether or not that does what you want, I'll suggest you consider a different query strategy which almost completely avoids the field name alias issue.  First test this query to confirm it returns suitable RefNum/UniqueID pairs. If your base query is named *Query1* ...

```sql
SELECT q1.RefNum, Min(q1.UniqueID) AS MinOfUniqueID
FROM Query1 AS q1
GROUP BY q1.RefNum
```

Assuming that one returns the correct rows, join it back to the base query to select only the base query rows which match ...

```sql
SELECT q.*
FROM
    Query1 AS q
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT q1.RefNum, Min(q1.UniqueID) AS MinOfUniqueID
        FROM Query1 AS q1
        GROUP BY q1.RefNum
    ) AS sub
    ON q.UniqueID = sub.MinOfUniqueID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you switch the view of your query to SQL view, you will see for example `AS FirstOfFirstName`.

Change this to `AS FirstName` and follow this on the other fields.

If you prefer doing this in design view you can do so by adding `FirstName:`
in front of the fieldname and so on:

[image]